# Foreign key/JoinColumn value erroneously always null

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

My Spring Boot JPA demo application has two entities, Student and Course, as defined below.

```java
import com.sp.utils.RandomStringIdGenerator;

@Entity(name="Student")
@Table(name="Student_master")
public class Student {      
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = RandomStringIdGenerator.generatorName)
    @GenericGenerator(name = RandomStringIdGenerator.generatorName, strategy = "com.sp.utils.RandomStringIdGenerator")    
    @Column(name="`Student ID`")
    private String StudentId;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CourseCode", referencedColumnName ="CourseCode")
    private Course course;
    
    @Column(name="`First Name`")
    private String firstName;   
    
    @Column(name="`Last Name`")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="`Mobile Number`")
    private Long mobileNumber;  
    
    @Column(name="City")
    private String city;
    
    @Column(name="Country")
    private String country;
        
    @Column(name="`Email ID`")
    private String emailId;
    
    @Column(name="`Date of Birth`")
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    
    public String getStudentId() {
        return StudentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(String StudentId) {
        this.StudentId = StudentId;
    }
    
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
        
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }   
        
    public Long getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }
    public void setMobileNumber(Long mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }       
    
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }   
    
    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }
    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }   
    
    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }
    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
    
    public Course getCourse() {             
        return course;
    }
    public void setCourse(Course course) {          
        this.course = course;
    }
    
    
}
```

```
@Entity(name="course")
@Table(name="course_master")
public class Course {
    
    @Column(name="CourseCode")
    @Id     
    private String courseCode;
    
    @Column(name="CourseDescription")
    private String courseDescription;
    
        
    public String getCourseCode() {
        return courseCode;
    }
    public void setCourseCode(String courseCode) {
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
    }
    
    public String getCourseDescription() {
        return courseDescription;
    }
    public void setCourseDescription(String courseDescription) {
        this.courseDescription = courseDescription;
    }
    
}
```

The Course entity for course_master table is read only. Meaning, there are already fixed entries and nothing can be added/updated or deleted.
When a Student is created/ saved, the CourseCode must be one of the CourseCode from Course.

Trying to create Student using postman with following input:

```
{
  "firstName": "Steven",
  "lastName": "Wilson",
  "mobileNumber": 2256443355,  
  "city": "Kualalumpur",
  "country": "Malaysia"
  "emailId": "steven.wilson@att.net",
  "dateOfBirth": "1976-09-04",
  "courseCode": "MA"
}
```

Though there is CourseCode provided in above input, it always generates a SQL error as below:

```
2021-05-23 17:24:44.218  WARN 154196 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2021-05-23 17:24:44.219 ERROR 154196 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'CourseCode' cannot be null
```

A student can be enrolled for single course only. Where as one course can be opted for, by many students. In this context, is the use of @OneToOne annotation correct?
Kindly point out and guide what change can help in saving the entity into db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is right: a `Student` can be enrolled in a `Course`, but a `Course` will be opted for many `Student`s, you are modeling a many to one relationship. Instead of using a `@OneToOne`, please, define the `course`field as follows in your `Student` entity:

```java
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="CourseCode", referencedColumnName ="CourseCode")
private Course course;
```

We use lazy fetching instead of the default eager fetch strategy applicable for many to one relationships, but feel free to let the default behavior if necessary.

Now, in order to persist your `Student` you need to perform something similar to the following:

```java
String courseCode = ...; // from your request
Course course = entityManager.find(Course.class, courseCode);

// Build you `Student` information
Student student = new Student();
// Populate fields appropriately
student.setFirstName(...);
student.setLastName(...);
// Set course information
student.setCourse(course);
 
entityManager.persist(student);
```

If you are using Spring Data JPA use the following instead:

```java
String courseCode = ...; // from your request
Course course = courseRepository.findByCourseCode(courseCode);
// Or
// Optional<Course> optCourse = courseRepository.findById(courseCode);
// if (optCourse.isPresent) { ... }

// Build you `Student` information
Student student = new Student();
// Populate fields appropriately
student.setFirstName(...);
student.setLastName(...);
// Set course information
student.setCourse(course);
 
studentRepository.save(student);
```

In fact, as explained in this [great Vlad Mihalcea article](https://vladmihalcea.com/manytoone-jpa-hibernate/), you do not need to actually fetch the `Course` entity from database, only a reference to it in order to establish the foreign key, so your code can be simplified as follows:

```java
String courseCode = ...; // from your request
// Not the use of getReference
Course course = entityManager.getReference(Course.class, courseCode);

// Build you `Student` information
Student student = new Student();
// Populate fields appropriately
student.setFirstName(...);
student.setLastName(...);
// Set course information
student.setCourse(course);
 
entityManager.persist(student);
```

And with Spring Data JPA:

```java
String courseCode = ...; // from your request
Course course = courseRepository.getById(courseCode);

// Build you `Student` information
Student student = new Student();
// Populate fields appropriately
student.setFirstName(...);
student.setLastName(...);
// Set course information
student.setCourse(course);
 
studentRepository.save(student);
```

In addition, for your comments, to properly receive your course code you need to provide the corresponding field in your `Student` class. Please, consider for instance:

```java
// Define the course code property in addition to course, and define it as neither insertable or updatable
@Column(name="CourseCode", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String courseCode;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="CourseCode", referencedColumnName ="CourseCode")
private Course course;

//...

// Define setters and getters

public void setCourseCode(String courseCode){
  this.courseCode = courseCode;
}

public String getCourseCode() {
  return this.courseCode;
}

//...
```

In addition, please, be sure that the `CourseCode`column in the `Student` table can be `null`: it seems for your logs an error reported by the database engine itself.

Comment: Thanks for detailing it out.   But I'm now stuck at courseCode received as null from  the request, though it's present in the request body. Any pointers to possible cause?

Comment: You are welcome @sap. Yes, please, see the updated answer. Please, can you try the suggested approach?

Comment: Thanks. Tried it. But didn't change the output.

Comment: That is very strange @sap. Were you able to receive the `courseCode` from the request information at least? In addition, how is your `CourseCode` column defined at database level? Is it defined as nullable? It seems for your logs an error reported by the database engine itself. Please, be sure that the `CourseCode` in the `Student` table can be `null`
.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I rechecked the code. There was a silly mistake of incorrect camel case use.  Now I have courseCode in StudentController.  Adding courseCode and getter/setters did the trick. Thanks a ton.

Comment: There is no need to apologize. You are very welcome @sap, I am happy to hear that you were able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you need to place the @OneToOne annotation in Course Entity too , Because you are maintaining One to One relation b/w Student and course . That's because this is a bidirectional relationship. The Course side of the relationship is called the non-owning side. This solution is for your current implementation but it is not the perfect way to solve it you must have to change the relationship from ONE TO ONE to --  Many To One

```
@JsonManagedReference  
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "course")
    private Student student ;

@JsonBackReference
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CourseCode", referencedColumnName ="CourseCode")
private Course course;
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried. But, it causes infinite loop of Students (same object) inside Course object, which is part of Student GET response.

Comment: These scenarios give you circular references which cause stack overflow error. You can overcome it by creating DTO and you can ignore parent in your child  in your DTO or you can use "JsonManagedRefrence" and  "JsonBackReference" to rectify circular reference  .
I am modifying the answer please check.

Comment: Right. I did this eventually.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that you forgot to set the course field before saving the entity.
You have to save the entity this way when the postman request arrives:

1. create new student entity and set the simple (non association) fields on it
2. find the Course in question by id
3. set the course on student
4. save your student entity

Your code should be something like this:

```
// ...
Course course = courseRespository.findById(courseCode);
student.setCourse(course);
studentRepository.save(student);
```

Edit: It should work with `@OneToOne`, but @ManyToOne would be better, because your entities are in `@ManyToOne` relation. https://vladmihalcea.com/manytoone-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: I understand this code snippet should be part of the StudentService. right? The issue there faced is courseCode itself is null.